# Creating a custom field in saved search based on text in another column

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches, suiteql

I am building a saved search where we have 2 fields where 1 of them only contains employee names but the 2nd one contains both employee name and vendor names. I want to create a column which only contains employee names from both columns. The second column is based on journal entries and just contains the employee name which I am trying to somehow filter but to no avail yet. Any help regarding how to achieve this result will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

I have tried a case statement where the text in the 2nd column equals employee name but it seems to be referencing only the data in the saved search and not the master employee list.